# How do I use wine?

Tags: wine, games, executable

After using Ubuntu for quite a while, I have decided to use it to be my primary operating system and will try to uninstall Windows. However, the only thing blocking me is that I can't use Linux for playing most of my games and some programs like MS Office, some sites tell me that Wine is the solution for this.

So how do I use Wine? I tried opening .exe files of certain games using wine but it all failed. Any help? Thanks :)

Comment: You are going to be far better off running windows apps in windows , either as a dual boot or VM, rather then wine. With wine you have to almost go application by application -

Answer (score 2):

Not every Windows program is working on Wine. You can check the list of supported programs [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/).

There's also PlayOnLinux, a software that uses Wine but it is easier thanks to a very intuitive GUI.

Remember, sometimes it's better to use open-source software (like LibreOffice) than emulate Windows closed-source programs (like the MS Office suite).

Comment: Wine is not an emulator...

Comment: True, technically is a compatibility layer. I expressed myself in the worst possible way, sorry. All the most relevant informations can be found here http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#head-c9e6502ad636315e905d07f7e44594757a6738e3